# Read values of entity reference within another entity reference in Paragraph preprocess - D9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

I have a content type that has a Paragraph entity reference field named "Grants". This "Grants" paragraph field has another paragraph entity reference field names "contacts". So the entity references are nested as :

```
Awards content type ---->(refers)--->Grants paragraph field--->(refers)--->Contacts paragraph field
```

I am trying to read the contacts reference fields in hook_preprocess_paragraph method and I cannot do that:

```
    function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(array &$variables) {
      $pval = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
      $paragraph = $pval->field_grant_contacts->getValue();
      foreach ( $paragraph as $element ) {
      $p = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::load( $element['target_id'] );
      $text = $p->field_contact_name->getValue();
     }
  dd($text);
    }
```

I am trying to reference the primary field - field_grant_contact. Through that I'm trying to read field_contact_name and the getValue method returns null. Any help on how to read nested entity reference fields?

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful method [Entity::referencedEntities](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AreferencedEntities/8.2.x) to get relations.
Also to get text value use `$p->field_contact_name->value`.

In your case try the next code:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(array &$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface $paragraph */
  $paragraph = $variables['elements']['#paragraph'];
  /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphInterface[] $contacts */
  $contacts = $paragraph->field_grant_contacts->referencedEntities();
  foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    $text = $contact->field_contact_name->value;
    var_dump($text);
  }
}
```